# Autorun программы с usb на windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, usb

Можно ли файлом autorun при подключении флешки в usb разъем сразу же запустить программу с флешки на windows 7? Читал много статей про то, что в винде 7 данная функция была убрана, но также читал что можно попробовать сделать флешку (не разъяснено как) наподобие CD, для которых эта функция работает. Если это возможно, то как?

Comment: Также читал о варианте про флешки U3, которые также якобы читаются как CD (насколько я понял).